# How can I hide past conversation messages when launching the smooch messenger?

Tags: smooch

https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web

I can't find any method to disable the past conversation from the smooch-web documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific method to "disable the past conversation" as of v4.12.13. However, there are ways to achieve this functionality as outlined in the Smooch documentation https://docs.smooch.io/guide/clearing-conversations/#clearing-conversations.